Embedded key value store cache
Are there any embedded alternatives to Memcached? Specifically, I'm looking for an open-source solution that can be used as an in-memory key-value storage within my application. I'm not concerned about data durability and persistence (e.g., I don't want something like RocksDB). I care about throughput and latency of reads and writes, and I want the storage to be embedded in my application rather than being a stand-alone service. And, I prefer it to support c/c++.

Are you willing to consider a commercial solution, or only open source?
If you're willing to consider commercial, there's eXtremeDB (disclosure: my company). It's not schema-less, but the schema can be as simple as defining a key/value. It was originally designed and optimized to be an embedded in-memory database.

Thanks! I'm looking for an open-source solution. I've edited the original question.
